# How to render JavaScript object in React, if an imported object has already been rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to render the `Page` object also, how can I render it?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import {Navbar, MainContent} from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
const Page = (
  <div>
    <h2>This is react</h2>
    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
  </div>
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Navbar />
    <MainContent />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

If I am including the `Page` object like normal react component the screen goes blank
[image: When I tried to render the Page object, the screen goes blank(Line 19)]

Whereas, if I delete the `Page` then it works fine
[image: When I do not render the Page object]

Answer (score 1):

**Simplest Method Is**

```
<React.StrictMode>
<Navbar />
<MainContent />
{page}
</React.StrictMode>
```

Otherwise make component and use it like above mentioned answer. However I used JSX(You can read it for getting more info & grasp more concepts, its powerful)

Comment: So, basically we need to use the angular brackets for the objects/components which are imported and curly braces for the object.

Comment: For components we used angular brackets and for objects/variables we used JSX. I'm also revising my react js concepts and found very good content here you can check https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_jsx.asp

Answer (score 0):

First, it's better to write your components name with Capital, so you can change it to `Page`.
Then, you can render it like other elements like:

```
<React.StrictMode>
    <Navbar />
    <MainContent />
    <Page />
</React.StrictMode>
```

You can change the order by the way.